# What is Activator.CreateInstance?

Tags: c#

What is Activator.CreateInstance? How can I use it?  Can I have an example please?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx

Comment: Why are you asking this question? With a bit more context we may be able to reasonably answer the question but as it stands, we have no idea what sort of information you're after (short of what the documentation provides).

Answer (score 2):

`Activator` abstracts the act of creating instances of arbitrary types. Use it to create instances of types picked at runtime. See [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) for examples.